# Query criteria does not work in mongoose query in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have database schema as follows:

```
var Items = new Schema({
    no_of_times_ordered:Number,
    item_name:String,
    item_tag:String,
    item_category:String,
    item_stock:Number,
    item_price:Number,
    item_img:String,
    item_illustrations:[String],
    item_liked:Boolean,
    no_of_likes:Number
},{ versionKey: false });


var FoodTruckSchema = new Schema({
    foodtruck_name:String,
    foodtruck_location:String,
    foodtruck_rating:Number,
    foodtruck_tag:String,
    foodtruck_timing:String,
    foodtruck_cusine:String,
    foodtruck_img:String,
    foodtruck_logo:String,
    item_list: [Items]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruck',FoodTruckSchema);
```

The query is as below:

```
var popularitems = function(req,res) {
    foodtr.find({ 'item_list.no_of_times_ordered': { $gt: 4000}},function(err,items){
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json({
            status : '200',
            message:'popular items list',
            data: items
        });
    });
```

Here I want items with no_of_times_order more than 3000 times, but query does not seem to work and it gives me every item in collection.

Comment: Isn't the query supposed to be `foodtr.find({ 'item_list.no_of_times_ordered': { $gt: 3000 } },function(err, items) {`?

Comment: Yes, it is same as you have said. But it is not working

Comment: Is it _foodtr_ or _foodtruck_?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query is wrong. If you want the **no_of_times_ordered**, you should specify it in the query. For example:

```
var popularitems = function(req,res) {
    foodtr.find({ 'item_list.no_of_times_ordered': { $gt: 4000}},function(err,items){
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json({
            status : '200',
            message:'popular items list',
            data: items
        });
    });
```

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: I did as you said, but the list is empty

Comment: I forgot to put the item_list before the nbr of items. Please consider the edited answer.

Comment: I did that, but it gives me the full list without any query process